# Где и когда использовать скобки в функции?

Tags: javascript, функции

Я не совсем понимаю где стоит использовать скобки в функции, а где нет. В инете пишется, что скобки используются при вызове функции, а функция без скобок, я так понимаю, используется, когда мы хотим просто использовать значение функции.

Но вот пример ниже. Здесь нужно использовать значение функции - прибавить к нему 1. Но в итоге прибавляется один ко всему коду функции.

```js
function func() {
  console.log('function');
  return 5;
}

console.log(1 + func);
```

Во втором примере опять используется значение функции **и тоже не используются скобки**, и все работает как надо:

```js
function func() {
  console.log('function');
  return 5;
}

let a = func;
a();
```

Можно как-то четко сказать где стоит писать без скобок, а где с?

P. S. Хотя я наверное больше не понимаю что является значением функции. Разве не return возвращает значение функции?

Comment: Без скобок вы используете саму функцию как объект. При этом ни о каком возвращаемом значении речи не может быть. А скобки после функции выполняют эту функцию и возвращают значение, написанное после return. Так что скобки нужны когда вы хотите выполнить функцию и использовать её возвращаемое значение, а не просто использовать сам объект функции без выполнения.

Comment: А `1 + функция` дают строку вида "1function()..." потому, что функция как объект в операции сложения преобразуется в строку её кода, и затем складывается с единицей как строка. Это преобразование эквивалентно такому коду: `(function(){}).toString()`

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev ага, понятно) спасибо! не проходила просто еще объекты

Answer (score 1):

Когда нужно *вызвать* функцию (выполнить код внутри нее) - нужны скобки. Когда коду нужно работать со ссылкой на *объект функции* - без скобок.

```
let a = func; // make variable a reference the same function object as func
a();          // call the function
```